# create stack as abstract data type in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to create stack data type in haskell to be able to write like this:

```
let a = emptyStack

push 10 a
//[10]

pop a 
[]
```

I want push to look like

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push a b = a:b
```

but I have problems with syntax, exactly how to declare this new data type, so that

```
let a = emptyStack 
:t a
```

would show Stack

any hints on syntax

Comment: This page has a nice minimal stack implementation: https://wiki.haskell.org/Abstract_data_type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your implementation for `push`. It uses the operator `:`. You can find out the type of that operator like this:

```
ghci> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So this operator takes an `a` (which represents an arbitrary type), and a sequence of `a`s, and returns the updated sequence. So your type `Stack` needs to be a sequence.

```
type Stack a = [a]
```

If you then define emptyStack like this:

```
emptyStack :: Stack a
emptyStack = []
```

You'll get the result you're looking for.

```
ghci> :t a
a :: Stack a
```

With that help, I think you'll be able to figure out how to write `pop`.

Comment: so abstract data types are created using 'type'? what about 'data' keyword?

Comment: `type` keyword creates type synonym, i.e. in this case `Stack a` and `[a]` are *completely* equivalent types. `data`, OTOH, creates new real type, that is, `data Stack a = Stack [a]` is different from plain `[a]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can write

```
import Data.Maybe

data Stack a = Stack [a] deriving Show

empty :: Stack a
empty = Stack []

push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x (Stack xs)= Stack (x:xs)

pop :: Stack a -> (Maybe a, Stack a)
pop (Stack []) = (Nothing, Stack [])
pop (Stack (x:xs)) = (Just x, Stack xs)
```

example

```
*Main> push 4 $ push 3 empty
Stack [4,3]
*Main> pop $ push 4 $ push 3 empty
(Just 4,Stack [3])
```

this aproach is strict checking the type arguments (in contrast to @mhwombat solution). One or other aproach is valid (one will be better than other in some cases and vice versa).

Comment: I would have used `newtype` here instead. `newtype` instead of `data` will not produce runtime overhead; in fact it is intended exactly for such situations.